# TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined using $http

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, callback, typeerror

i'm creating a service for http communication, i need some way to return a value..
But I get a Type Error , when I call success ;( ..

**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined"**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, apiService){    
  $scope.GetJson = function() {
    apiService('post','http://myApiAddress', "{'dataFn': 'userInfo'}")
    .success(function(response) { // ERROR !!! TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
      $scope.userinfo = response;
    })
    .error(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

})

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

var module = angular.module('httpService',[]);
module.factory('apiService',['$http',function($http){

 var userAuthority = true; // or false (boolean Value)

 var apiService = function (method, url, param){
    if(userAuthority){
      apiService.idCheck().success( function(res) {
        return $http[method](url, param);
      })
      .error( function(err) {
          console.log(err);
      })
    }
    else {
      return $http[method](url, param);
    }
  };
  apiService.idCheck = function () {
    return $http.get('http://myApiAddress');
  };
}])
```

I'm looking for one of two answers:

1. Why is the success callback returning an error?
2. How can I fix this error ?

Comment: What's the response you are trying to get? if the post was successful is that it?

Comment: added code the last line "return apiService; "

Comment: Gio Perez //  i want to get JSON data, error has sometime  arisen

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a `factory`, you need to return an `Object`. Your factory `apiService` returns `undefined`.

Add this line `return apiService`.

---

### Update

#### Why is the error?

You are getting this error because when you call `apiService`, it will call another **async** function `idCheck`. Meanwhile, in function `apiService`, here:

```
return $http[method](url, param);
```

is not returning to `apiService`. Instead, it is returning to the anonymous function:

```
function(res) {
    return $http[method](url, param);
})
```

So, the return value of `apiService` is `undefined`.

### How to fix?

Create a deferred/promise object manually:

```
module.factory('apiService',['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
...
var apiService = function (method, url, param){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(userAuthority){
        apiService.idCheck().success(function(res) {
            $http[method](url, param).success(function(res) {
                deferred.resolve(res);
            }).error(function(err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        }).error( function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    } else {
        return $http[method](url, param);
    }
};
...
```

For your reference: [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: sorry i forgot writing "return apiService" 
Then added code the last line "return apiService; " 
But error is same